# Running an observable into a zone.js

Tags: angular, rxjs, zone.js

I have a GPS plugin providing locations out of an angular zone. The changes are therefore not detected by angular and the view keeps stuck with the same values.

Of course, I could subscribe to this observable from the controller and do something like that.

```
$mySourceOutOfZone.subscribe((value)=>{
            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.value = value;
            });
})
```

And the view will simply use the value like:

```
<span>{{value}}</span>
```

But I would like to avoid having to subscribe to the controller and using the imperative style way.

How could I have this observable to run inside an angular zone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there is a plugin dedicated to [rxjs and zones:](https://github.com/ksachdeva/rxjs-zone-operators/blob/master/README.md)

The zone can be bound to any rxjs stream using

```js
.enterZone(this.ngZone)
```

or using the pipe operator:

```js
.pipe(enterZone(this.ngZone))
```

Answer (score 22):

When using RxJs 6+, a custom pipe operator can wrap the observable's behavior in a `zone.run()` for the specified zone.

```js
import { Observable, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export function runInZone<T>(zone: NgZone): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return (source) => {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const onNext = (value: T) => zone.run(() => observer.next(value));
      const onError = (e: any) => zone.run(() => observer.error(e));
      const onComplete = () => zone.run(() => observer.complete());
      return source.subscribe(onNext, onError, onComplete);
    });
  };
}
```

The operator can then be added to an observable, letting you be explicit about when to change zone contexts.

```js
return exampleObservable.pipe(
  runInZone(this.zone)
);
```

Comment: No dependency required, still accurate and up to date, worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: For RxJS 7 i changed this to:
return (source) => {
        return new Observable(observer => {
            return source.subscribe({
                next: (value: T) => zone.run(() => observer.next(value)),
                error: (e: any) => zone.run(() => observer.error(e)),
                complete: () => zone.run(() => observer.complete())
            });
        });
    };

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this patch.
Add this line inside `polyfills.ts` after import `zone.js`.

```
import `zone.js/dist/zone-patch-rxjs`;
```

So `subscription callback` will run in the zone when it call `.subscribe`.