# Capacitor plugins with Angular and Rxjs - Stream capacitor plugin in NgZone context

Tags: angular, rxjs, capacitor, rxjs-pipeable-operators, capacitor-plugin

I’m using the `CapacitorPurchases` plugin (but any plugin can have this situation) and methods return promises with results.
Normally I use something like

```
const result = await CapacitorPurchases.getPurchaserInfo();
this.ngZone.run(()=>{
   // do something with result
})
```

now I have a situation where I prefer to use rxjs and “complex” stream pipes with `switchMap` and other things. If I write

```
from( from(CapacitorPurchases.getPurchaserInfo()))
 .pipe(switchMap(value=>{
  this.a = value;
  return this.httpService.call()
})
```

the content of `switchMap` is run outside of the `ngZone` context
but if I write

```
from( from(CapacitorPurchases.getPurchaserInfo()))
 .pipe(switchMap(value=>{
  this.ngZone.run(()=>{
   this.a = value;
  })
 return this.httpService.call()
})
```

or other combination, I can lose data.
Do you know if there is a way to create a zone context with a stream pipe?

Comment: Have a look at this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928645/running-an-observable-into-a-zone-js

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After seeing and trying the answer postred @Džan Operta the best solution in to implement a pipe that re-enter in the ngZone.

I quote the code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57452361/1648495):

```
import { Observable, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

export function runInZone<T>(zone: NgZone): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return (source) => {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      const onNext = (value: T) => zone.run(() => observer.next(value));
      const onError = (e: any) => zone.run(() => observer.error(e));
      const onComplete = () => zone.run(() => observer.complete());
      return source.subscribe(onNext, onError, onComplete);
    });
  };
}
```

The other solution in the answer ([rxjs-zone-operators plugin](https://github.com/ksachdeva/rxjs-zone-operators)) seems loosing the type of the data in the pipe chain.